Set language in preseed for debian-installer for console
The preseed contains the following parameter:
d-i debian-installer/locale string ru_RU.UTF-8

and when installing in graphical mode, the language is selected as needed, but when installing in console mode, the list of languages ​​consists only of C and English (as in the screenshot below)
debian install console output
If I specify in preseed like this:
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8

then the installer still stops at the language selection screen.
Is it possible to somehow make sure that in console mode there is an entire list of languages ​​and select Russian?
If not, how can I specify the language in the preseed file for auto-installing Debian in console output mode?
I tried setting these parameters:
d-i debian-installer/locale string ru_RU.UTF-8

or
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8

or
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string en

then the installer still stops at the language selection screen.
It is expected that during installation the Russian language (preferably) or at least English was selected automatically in console mode

I added the language and country parameters - and the installation moved on. Well, at the same time I added supported-locales, the locale settings section turned out like this:
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string RU
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select ru
d-i localechooser/supported-locales multiselect ru_RU.UTF-8

